# error: init(type:style) is unavailable PKPaymentButton creation error in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have been figuring this out , I am getting this error :

```
error: init(type:style) is unavailable
```

PKPaymentButton creation error in Swift 4

after 5 hours of hit and try when i changed version of swift from 4.0 to 3.2 then build was successful.

Is this a swift error ? anyone has filed a bug ??

My XCode is 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Seems Swift 4 & iOS 11 SDK does not import `init(type:style:)` any more.

Maybe you can use `init(paymentButtonType:paymentButtonStyle:)`

[`init(paymentButtonType: PKPaymentButtonType, paymentButtonStyle: PKPaymentButtonStyle)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentbutton/1617842-init)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: PKPaymentButtonType.buy, paymentButtonStyle: PKPaymentButtonStyle.black)

Thankyou

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).